# twitter bootstrap + grails kickstart breaks jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I'm using grails kickstart to add twitter bootstrap on my app and it's causing problems with jquery libraries. I can't invoke functions on DOM objects:

What I've got:

```
<script>

$(function()
{
    //Loads the modal when page loads
    $.post('${createLink(controller: 'task', action:'create')}',
    function(data)
    {
        $('#AndersonModal').html(data);
    }, "html");

    $('#andersonTest').click(function ()
        {
            console.log("modal button clicked");
            $('#AndersonModal').modal('show');
        });
});
</script>

<a id="andersonTest" href='#'>Anderson</a>

<div id="AndersonModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

When I click the link it fires the js, but says that 'modal' is not a function

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function 1:129
Empty string passed to getElementById(). bundle-bundle_bootstrap_defer.js:4
"modal button clicked"
```

However everything works, the modals work, I just can't use js to make them to appear...
Indeed it is happening with any kind of library that add a function in a DOM object like $('#someID').someFunction();. It's always the same error:

```
"TypeError: $(...).someFunction is not a function"
```

Does anyone have any idea about how can I solve it?

The plugins on my app:

```
plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.2'
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
        compile ":mail:1.0.6"
        compile ":kickstart-with-bootstrap:1.1.0"
        compile ":rest:0.7"
        compile ":modernizr:latest.integration"
        compile ":uploadr:0.8.2"
        compile ":quartz:1.0.1"//latest.integration" //1.0.1"

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.13" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.1"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
        runtime ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1'
    }
```

Edit:

The modules being used:

```
<g:javascript src="fastclick.js"/>
<r:require modules="jquery"/> <%-- jQuery is required for Bootstrap! --%>
<r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
<r:require modules="bootstrap_utils"/>

<r:layoutResources />
<g:layoutHead />
```

Comment: Usually I see this when I haven't loaded the proper resources into the page. If you are using kickstart, then all of the essentials should be loaded in the layout content.gsp, but without being able to see your page, I can't tell what is in or not.

Comment: @SteveHole, thanks, I found out that it is a conflict with different versions of jQuery being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it happens due a conflict because more than one jQuery version is being loaded. Therefore I need to use [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to solve it:

```
$('#andersonTest').click(function ()
    {
        $2 = jQuery.noConflict( true );
        console.log("modal button clicked");
        $2('#AndersonModal').modal('show');
    });
```